# Debian installation from USB: "the logical volume vm-sys-net-private on qubes_dom0 could not be deleted"

Tags: system-installation, hard-disk, dd, xen, qubes

I tried Qubes OS and found out that it is too heavy and complicated for me. So I tried to install Debian from a flashed USB. However, the installer gives the following error:

`the logical volume vm-sys-net-private on qubes_dom0 could not be deleted`

I have a Bodhi Linux installer on another flashed USB and that gives the same error. Asking about this on the Qubes OS forum resulted in an answer suggesting the use of

"`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M` or something"

I've been reading abouf the `dd` command and it seems to be a legit way of wiping out contents of a hard drive. `lsblk` gives the following output:

```
user@personal:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
xvda    202:0    1    20G  0 disk
├─xvda1 202:1    1   200M  0 part
├─xvda2 202:2    1     2M  0 part
└─xvda3 202:3    1  19.8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   1     2G  0 disk /var/spool/cron
                                  /usr/local
                                  /home
                                  /rw
xvdc    202:32   1    10G  0 disk
├─xvdc1 202:33   1     1G  0 part [SWAP]
└─xvdc3 202:35   1     9G  0 part
xvdd    202:48   1 510.7M  1 disk
```

How should I wirte the `dd` command in order to succeed with the installer? If I wipe out everything, does the computer boot from the USB?

Comment: Is this on Xen? You might find it simpler to start over with a new domain.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes Qubes starts "with Xen hypervisor". I don't have any idea what "starting over with a new domain" means.

Comment: I’m probably interpreting this incorrectly, but your `lsblk` output gives the impression you’re trying to install a new distribution inside the existing Qubes dom0 (see [the Xen wiki](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Domain)). This would be similar to re-installing a different operating system in a guest VM — it’s usually simpler to delete the obsolete VM and create a new one. However I get the impression that what you really want to do is erase Qubes entirely. How are you booting the USB keys?

Comment: Yes, I want to erase Qubes and partitions completely and install Debian. I press F11 multiple times as my laptop is starting up to enter boot menu. From there I select the USB and get into the Debian installation menu. `lsblk` is printed from Qubes after starting up normally instead of the USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it was the `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M` command that worked. I booted from a Debian live USB to get a view of the actual hard drive instead of viewing the virtual machines on Qubes OS and replaced `sda` with the one found from my system containing all the Qubes files.